# How to read a complex input with istream&, string& and getline in c++?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++, so I apologize if this isn't a good question but I really need help in understanding how to use istream.

There is a project I have to create where it takes several amounts of input that can be on one line or multiple and then pass it to a vector (this is only part of the project and I would like to try the rest on my own), for example if I were to input this...

```
>> aaa    bb
>> ccccc
>> ddd fff  eeeee
```

Makes a vector of strings with "aaa", "bb", "ccccc", "ddd", "fff", "eeeee"

The input can be a char or string and the program stops asking for input when the return key is hit.

I know getline() gets a line of input and I could probably use a while loop to try and get the input such as...(correct me if I'm wrong)

```
while(!string.empty())
     getline(cin, string);
```

However, I don't truly understand istream and it doesn't help that my class has not gone over pointers so I don't know how to use istream& or string& and pass it into a vector. On the project description, it said to NOT use stringstream but use functionality from getline(istream&, string&). Can anyone give somewhat of a detailed explanation as to how to make a function using getline(istream&, string&) and then how to use it in the main function?

Any little bit helps!

Comment: The solution will depend on what `aaa` `bb` `ccccc` `ddd` `fff` `eeeee` are permitted to be. You will have to be _specific_ about your constraints/requirements.

Comment: Actually to be fair, if you've been banned from using stream formatted I/O, then you have to do the parsing yourself anyway so it doesn't really matter. Fact remains we can't really answer this without details.

Comment: Not really sure if you're asking how to parse the data or how to use getline or how to make your own getline (the function taking `istream&, string&` already exists!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "if you've been banned from using stream formatted I/O" i don't find that part in the q?

Comment: How do you know that the user is done with input? Is there a fixed number of strings to read? Or some magic value that ends input?

Comment: Oh yeah I'll add that now. You know the user is done with input when the return key is hit and the letters and input can be a char or string. I want the function to notice spaces and tabs to separate the input to where something like aaa and bb are their own strings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  for your third comment, I would like to know how to use getline(istream&, string&) to solve my problem

Comment: Is there a file or input format?  How does one determine how many columns per line?

Comment: What is used to separate columns (fields) and records?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is an input format and the columns per line is each line in the first code (each >> is a new line of input)

Comment: Your C++ book teaches you how to use getline.

Comment: @Swordfish: _"On the project description, it said to NOT use stringstream but use functionality from getline(istream&, string&)"_ Stringstream (perhaps in combo with formatted extraction from the original stream) is what you'd use to "cheat". Restricting to `getline` means _no_ formatted extraction from the original stream plus you then have to parse the resulting `string`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Its a little vague. But i guess it could be interpreted in that way.

Comment: @Swordfish Doesn't seem at all vague to me but to each their own.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OT: You might want to reconsider the usage of the phrase in the 2nd half of your last comment for where it got famous.

Comment: @Swordfish I don't follow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedem_das_Seine)

Comment: @Swordfish As the article says, it's a common Latin phrase. It became a common English phrase. It has no specific relationship to Nazi Germany, particularly when I don't say it in German. But I thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way already; solely, you'd have to pre-fill the string with some dummy to enter the while loop at all. More elegant:

```
std::string line;
do
{
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
}
while(!line.empty());
```

This should already do the trick reading line by line (but possibly multiple words on one line!) and exiting, if the user enters an empty line (be aware that whitespace followed by newline won't be recognised as such!).

However, if anything on the stream goes wrong, you'll be trapped in an endless loop processing previous input again and again. So best check the stream state as well:

```
if(!std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // this is some sample error handling - do whatever you consider appropriate...
    std::cerr << "error reading from console" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

As there might be multiple words on a single line, you'd yet have to split them. <s>There are several ways to do so, quite an easy one is using an `std::istringstream` – you'll discover that it ressembles to what you likely are used to using `std::cin`:</s>

```
    std::istringstream s(line);
    std::string word;
    while(s >> word)
    {
        // append to vector...
    }
```

Be aware that using `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace and stops after first trailing one (or end of stream, if reached), so you don't have to deal with explicitly.

OK, you're not allowed to use `std::stringstream` (well, I used `std::`**i**`stringstream`, but I suppose this little difference doesn't count, does it?). Changes matter a little, it gets more complex, on the other hand, we can decide ourselves what counts as words an what as separators... We might consider punctuation marks as separators just like whitespace, but allow digits to be part of words, so we'd accept e. g. `ab.7c d` as `"ab", "7c", "d"`:

```
auto begin = line.begin();
auto end = begin;
while(end != line.end()) // iterate over each character
{
    if(std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(*end)))
    {
        // we are inside a word; don't touch begin to remember where
        // the word started
        ++end;
    }
    else
    {
        // non-alpha-numeric character! 
        if(end != begin)
        {
            // we discovered a word already
            // (i. e. we did not move begin together with end)
            words.emplace_back(begin, end);
            // ('words' being your std::vector<std::string> to place the input into) 
        }
        ++end;
        begin = end; // skip whatever we had already
    }
}
// corner case: a line might end with a word NOT followed by whitespace
// this isn't covered within the loop, so we need to add another check:
if(end != begin)
{
    words.emplace_back(begin, end);
}
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to adjust to different interpretations of what is a separator and what counts as word (e. g. `std::isalpha(...) || *end == '_'` to detect underscore as part of words, but digits not). There are quite a few [helper functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) you might find useful...

Comment: I mostly understand your solution however, I have never seen emplace before and it doesn't seem to work on a string. Not to mention, now when I put in an input I am stuck possibly in an infinite loop because the program does nothing after I display a message and ask for input

Comment: [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) exists since C++11 (if your compiler is already a bit aged, you might have to explicitly enable it) and essentially does a placement new with the arguments provided, i. e. it skips creating an intermediate object as you'd need with `words.push_back(std::string(begin, end));` - which would be the pre-C++11 variant; the same [std::string constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (6th one) as shown here would be used within emplace_back as well.

Comment: *'does nothing after [...]'* - this is not true (provided you integrated the code from my answer). It will place the words in a vector, solely, this is not visible from outside. After the outer do while loop terminates, you might print out all words in the vector to console, then you'd see them again. If you want immediate reaction to input (without having to enter empty line first), you can print out the words to console, too, immediately after recognising one.

Comment: And a good tip for you: don't just copy and paste my solution (I personally don't care if you do so...), you won't learn anything from. First understand it, then rewrite it on your own. Be aware that you do not *need* to use iterators as I did (but *can*, of course), there are plenty of other options as well (e. g. using indices instead of iterators). Even a range-based for loop is possible (`for(auto c : line)`), you then could append the character to an intermediate string object, if in word, and on separator, push the intermediate to vector (don't for get to clear the word then).

Comment: Oh (re-reading your comment), and just to make clear: `words` is a `std::vector<std::string>` that needs to be defined before the outermost do-while loop! I assumed this to be clear from the question (*'[...] and then pass it to a vector [...]'*) - sorry for confusion - added a comment to the answer.

Comment: I actually was trying to read emplace_back online to try an make sense of your answer and how I could modify it to my liking because I wanted to try some delimiters and check if the string was empty. I just tried out your program and it completely works so I'm gonna have to do some more reading about emplace because what you wrote was cool. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could input the value of the first column, then call functions based on the value:

```
void Process_Value_1(std::istream& input, std::string& value);
void Process_Value_2(std::istream& input, std::string& value);

int main()
{
  // ...
  std::string first_value;
  while (input_file >> first_value)
  {
     if (first_value == "aaa")
     {
         Process_Value_1(input_file, first_value);
     }
     else if (first_value = "ccc")
     {
         Process_Value_2(input_file, first_value);
     }
     //...
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A sample function could be:

```
void Process_Value_1(std::istream& input, std::string& value)
{
  std::string b;
  input >> b;
  std::cout << value << "\t" << b << endl;
  input.ignore(1000, '\n'); // Ignore until newline.
}
```

There are other methods to perform the process, such as using tables of function pointers and `std::map`.

Comment: This looks rather like a parser for specific input - whereas, if I understood the question right, it is about reading arbitrary words distributed over arbitrary number of lines and only extract each of these words, without applying any meaning to them...